# Simpler definition of equivalence relation

Tags: definition, equivalence-relations

Is there something wrong with the following two-axiom definition of an equivalence relation?

A relation $R \subseteq A\times A$ is an equivalence relation iff:

1. For all $x \in A, xRx$
2. For all $x, y, z \in A, xRy$ and $xRz$ implies $yRz$

Given $R \subseteq A \times A$ which satisfies (1) and (2), $R$ is reflexive by (1). 
For $x, y \in A$ with $xRy$, we have $xRx$ so by (2) we have $yRx$ and $R$ is symmetric. 
For $x, y, z \in A$ with $xRy$ and $yRz$ we have $yRx$ so by (2) we have $xRz$ and $R$ is transitive. 
So $R$ is an equivalence relation. 

Given an equivalence relation $R \subseteq A \times A$, (1) holds. 
For any $x, y, z \in A$ with $xRy$ and $xRz$ we have $yRx$ so $yRz$ and (2) holds. 

I have only seen somenthing similar to this in a wikipedia page about Tarski's axioms for euclidean geometry. If there is nothing wrong with the proof, why don't we prefer a two-axiom definition over a three-axiom one? The usual definition surely seems much more natural but I can't even find something on the internet for the second one. Is this something generally discused about equivalence relations (something like the dependance of the axioms of a metric space)?

Comment: Just quick question: did you checked reverse direction i.e. from equivalence relation can you get your $1,2$ ?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in the question

Comment: Fewer axioms does not always equate with simpler axioms, so preferring a two-axiom definition over a three-axiom definition is not automatic.

Comment: Still, though, you've got Euclid on your side. Your (2) is present in the "Common Notions" of [Euclid's elements](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Euclid/Elements.pdf): "Things equal to the same thing are equal to each other."

Comment: A thought: *transitivity* as a notion is important by itself, cf. "transitive closure", "partially ordered set" etc. - so all things equal it is probably natural to include it into the set of axioms outright.